# acquireToken always fails with "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"

Tags: javascript, adal, adal.js

When using `acquireToken`, it appends a hidden iframe to the page where it attempts to retrieve a new access token. However, this always fails with the following error:

> Token renewal operation failed due to timeout

Are there any special requirements for the iframe or the `redirectUri` setting (it's currently left with the default which should be `window.location.href`)? Does the redirect endpoint need to implement any logic to handle it? Here's the configuration:

```
context = new AuthenticationContext({
  tenant: '<my tenant id>',
  clientId: '<my client id>',
  popUp: true,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
});
```

`context.login()` has been already been done by the time I call `acquireToken`, so there is a valid id token in the context. The `acquireToken` call falls back to `acquireTokenPopup` if it fails, which works as expected. My current workaround is to just call `getCachedToken` instead of `acquireToken`, but I would really like to get `acquireToken` to work, as it's a nicer user experience without the flash of a popup window.

Comment: I have the same problem. A fix of the devs (or at least a hint for a workaround) would be awesome!